# Oracle Package Function call fails in .NET

Tags: oracle11g, .net-4.0, ado.net

I am converting a java application to a .NET application, and need to interface with a Package Function. The function inserts into several tables in a standardized way, and so writing a separate query to accomplish my goal is not an option.

From reading around here, and elsewhere, I understand that to access a function in .NET, you treat it as a stored procedure. I believe I've got the ADO code written correctly, but I'm getting exceptions I shouldn't be getting.

My code:

```
Dim conn As OracleConnection = Database.DataConnection //A property that opens the connection on Get
Dim cmd As New OracleCommand()
cmd.Connection = conn
cmd.CommandText = "pkg_insert_stock.create_stock"
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure

...//input values assigned here

'Return parameters
cmd.Parameters.Add("v_stock_id", OracleDbType.Varchar2, ParameterDirection.ReturnValue)

'Input parameters
cmd.Parameters.Add("p_cust_num", OracleDbType.Int32, custNum, ParameterDirection.Input)
cmd.Parameters.Add("p_group_code", OracleDbType.Varchar2, groupCode, ParameterDirection.Input)
cmd.Parameters.Add("p_searchkey1", OracleDbType.Varchar2, search1, ParameterDirection.Input)
cmd.Parameters.Add("p_searchkey2", OracleDbType.Varchar2, search2, ParameterDirection.Input)
cmd.Parameters.Add("p_searchkey3", OracleDbType.Varchar2, search3, ParameterDirection.Input)
cmd.Parameters.Add("p_unit_qty", OracleDbType.Int32, unitQty, ParameterDirection.Input)
cmd.Parameters.Add("p_price", OracleDbType.Int32, price, ParameterDirection.Input)
cmd.Parameters.Add("p_width", OracleDbType.Decimal, width, ParameterDirection.Input)
cmd.Parameters.Add("p_basis_weight", OracleDbType.Decimal, basisWeight, ParameterDirection.Input)
cmd.Parameters.Add("p_costingkind", OracleDbType.Int32, costingKind, ParameterDirection.Input)
cmd.Parameters.Add("p_quality", OracleDbType.Varchar2, quality, ParameterDirection.Input)
cmd.Parameters.Add("p_sales_desc", OracleDbType.Varchar2, salesDesc, ParameterDirection.Input)
cmd.Parameters.Add("p_purchase_desc", OracleDbType.Varchar2, purchaseDesc, ParameterDirection.Input)

'Execute the stored procedure
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
articleNum = CType(cmd.Parameters.Item("v_stock_id").Value, Integer)
conn.Close()
```

The function signature:

```
PACKAGE pkg_insert_stock AS
function create_stock(p_cust_num in NUMBER, p_group_code in VARCHAR2, p_searchkey1 in VARCHAR2, p_searchkey2 in VARCHAR2, p_searchkey3 in VARCHAR2, p_unit_qty in NUMBER, p_price in NUMBER, p_width in NUMBER, p_basis_weight in NUMBER, p_costingkind in NUMBER, p_quality in VARCHAR2,p_sales_desc in VARCHAR2, p_purchase_desc in VARCHAR2) return VARCHAR2;
END pkg_insert_stock;
```

My problem (at the moment) is that I receive ORA-01403: no data found on this line of the function:

```
select round(((sysdate - to_date('01-JAN-1970','DD-MON-YYYY')) * (86400)),0) into v_timestamp from dual;
```

This doesn't make any sense to me. Sysdate is not something that can come back "no data found," unless I misunderstand how that works. Also, this function works just fine on our Java-based production server, as is.

Everything that I've been able to find about accessing functions and stored procedures tells me I've got this set up correctly, but clearly that is not the case. I've verified that all my input variables have values at runtime, so I'm at a loss right now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turned out that there was some missing data - just not on the line indicated by Oracle. The field in question sometimes does not contain data, but usually does. The function is coded to handle missing there, but for whatever reason the function is exiting with an error, rather than executing the PLSQL code. That, however, is a different issue.